# Netbook Ubuntu installation broke Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation

When I installed Ubuntu for netbook about a year ago it broke something in Windows 7 and now Windows 7 goes to blue screen all the time. I don't use Windows anymore but it might be nice to fix. Any suggestions on what has happened and a fix as I don't have the Windows Installation CD. Is there a simple fix?

So just trying to boot windows (its been a long time)
Its runs the loading bar for about 3 minutes then flashes to blue screen for about 1 second then reboots by itself.

Ubuntu is 2.6.32-37 netbook version.

Hope this helps if not ask and I will try to see more.

Comment: This question does not give enough information to help.. What 'blue screen'? stoppage error? when do you see this? what version of Ubuntu? can you provide ***any*** more information about your problem.

Comment: Heh sorry just meant the dreaded windows blue screen for boot failure. I will come back with full details in a moment for you thanks

Comment: that really doesn't tell us what the issue is.. there are different blue screen messages depending on the problem. Take a picture of the blue screen and upload it, or write it down and type us up the message.

Answer (score 1):

there is not enough info but lets me guess, ubuntu will not harm the windows in any way except if you shrink your windows system partition mostly the c and then install the ubuntu on the new partition. if this is the case i guess there is nothing you can do to fix windows from ubuntu you need windows cd to fix that

Comment: didnt touch partition I guess its just windows that one day went AWOL dont have disck as its only a netbook with pre-intstalled. thanks anyway

Comment: @Antony If windows was preinstalled on the netbook what did you do with the recovery partition when you installed ubuntu? - you should be able to select it when GRUB loads and use it to recover your windows install.

Comment: yup mark has a good point if its a netbook then you have a partition to recover or fix your windows and it depend on the brand but i guess you can get to it through your boot screen and then fix your windows